# Append only matching columns to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sort of 'master' dataframe that I'd like to append only matching columns from another dataframe to

```
df:
  A  B  C
  1  2  3

df_to_append:
  A  B  C  D  E
  6  7  8  9  0
```

The problem is that when I use `df.append()`, It also appends the unmatched columns to df.

```
df = df.append(df_to_append, ignore_index=True)
Out:
A  B  C   D   E
1  2  3  NaN NaN
6  7  8   9   0
```

But my desired output is to drop columns D and E since they are not a part of the original dataframe? Perhaps I need to use `pd.concat`? I don't think I can use `pd.merge` since I don't have anything unique to merge on.

Comment: Consider using `pd.concat` with `joint='inner'`.

Comment: Why  not use the list of column names from the "master" to filter the other before doing the append?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `concat` `join='inner`

```
pd.concat([df,df_to_append],join='inner')
Out[162]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
0  6  7  8
```

Answer (score 3):

Just select the columns common to both `df`s:

`df.append(df_to_append[df.columns], ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to get the list of columns common to both dataframes using `df.columns`, but if you don't know that all of the original columns are included in `df_to_append`, then you need to find the intersection of the two sets:

```
cols = list(set(df.columns) & set(df_to_append.columns)) 
df.append(df_to_append[cols], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

While the OP did not explicitly say so (and did not complain), their mention of *"sort of 'master' dataframe"* imply to me that the column number of the resulting dataframe should not change.

This is the case for [BENY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55541023/20831802)'s and [cfort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55540651/20831802)'s answers if and only if the column names of the dataframes to append are guaranteed to be strict supersets of the column names of the original dataframe.

**Only [Eliot K](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55540753/20831802)'s solution ensures that the width of the original dataframe is retained**, filling up any missing columns in the dataframe to append with `NaN`s. If you come across the question with this particular concern, like I did, then this is the way to go.

In the following I will summarize the three solutions and show what they do.

---

#### Prepare test data

Let's first create some dataframes, starting with the reference dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [4, 5], 'C': [8, 6]})
```

This would look like this:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  4  8
1  2  5  6
```

Now let's create a set of dataframes to append:

- `df_union`: has exactly the same columns as `df`
- `df_subset_`: has some of the columns of `df`, but not all
- `df_intersection`: has some, but not all, columns of `df`, and some additional ones
- `df_disjoint`: has none of the columns of `df`
- `df_superset`: has all of the columns of `df` and some additional columns

```py
df_union = df.copy()
df_subset = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [4, 5]})
df_intersection = pd.DataFrame({'C': [8, 6], 'D': [1, 2], 'E': [4, 5]})
df_disjoint = pd.DataFrame({'D': [1, 2], 'E': [4, 5], 'F': [8, 6]})
df_superset = df.merge(df_disjoint, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

We end up wit the following column names per dataframe:

| Dataframe | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `df` | YES | YES | YES |  |  |  |
| `df_union` | YES | YES | YES |  |  |  |
| `df_subset` | YES | YES |  |  |  |  |
| `df_intersection` |  |  | YES | YES | YES |  |
| `df_disjoint` |  |  |  | YES | YES | YES |
| `df_superset` | YES | YES | YES | YES | YES | YES |

Let's now use the test data

---

#### Inner join ([BENY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55541023/20831802))

```py
pd.concat([df, df_union], join='inner')
pd.concat([df, df_subset], join='inner')
pd.concat([df, df_intersection], join='inner')
pd.concat([df, df_disjoint], join='inner')
pd.concat([df, df_superset], join='inner')
```

Using this strategy, we cannot get more columns than what was in the original dataframe, but we can get *less* (including none at all).

When concatenating each of the test dataframes to `df`, we get the following columns for `df_out`:

| Dataframe | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `df_union` | YES | YES | YES |
| `df_subset` | YES | YES |  |
| `df_intersection` |  |  | YES |
| `df_disjoint` |  |  |  |
| `df_superset` | YES | YES | YES |

**Conclusion:**

- Prevents expansion of the reference dataframe; any additional columns in dataframe to append are dropped
- Does **not** prevent shrinkage of the reference dataframe
- Good solution if dataframe shrinkage is acceptable *or* if it is guaranteed that dataframes to append have at least all of the columns in the reference dataframe

---

#### Appending only columns in reference dataframe [cfort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55540651/20831802)

```py
df.append(df_union[df.columns], ignore_index=True)
df.append(df_subset[df.columns], ignore_index=True)
df.append(df_intersection[df.columns], ignore_index=True)
df.append(df_disjoint[df.columns], ignore_index=True)
df.append(df_superset[df.columns], ignore_index=True)
```

This solution is similar to the inner join from above, with one important distinction: The operation will raise a `KeyError` if the dataframe to append does not contain all of the columns in the reference dataframe.

Appending the following dataframes works, and the `df_out` dataframe will contain all of the columns in the reference dataframe:

| Dataframe | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `df_union` | YES | YES | YES |
| `df_superset` | YES | YES | YES |

For the following dataframes, a `KeyError` is raised:

| Dataframe | Outcome |
| --- | --- |
| `df_subset` | `KeyError` |
| `df_intersection` | `KeyError` |
| `df_disjoint` | `KeyError` |

**Conclusion:**

- Prevents expansion of the reference dataframe; any additional columns in dataframe to append are dropped
- Prevents shrinkage of the reference dataframe by raising a `KeyError`
- Good solution if dataframe resizing is not acceptable; `KeyError` can be used to handle dataframes with missing columns relative to the reference dataframe

---

#### Appending only columns in *both* dataframes [Eliot K](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55540753/20831802)

```py
df.append(df_union[list(set(df.columns) & set(df_union.columns))], ignore_index=True)
df.append(df_subset[list(set(df.columns) & set(df_subset.columns))], ignore_index=True)
df.append(df_intersection[list(set(df.columns) & set(df_intersection.columns))], ignore_index=True)
df.append(df_disjoint[list(set(df.columns) & set(df_disjoint.columns))], ignore_index=True)
df.append(df_superset[list(set(df.columns) & set(df_superset.columns))], ignore_index=True)
```

This solution uses the same technical approach as the previous one, but instead of selecting from the dataframe to append all of the columns of the reference dataframe (which may not be available), only those columns are selected that are available in *both* dataframes.

In this way, the solution is similar to the inner join, but because of `.append()`'s behavior, the resulting dataframe cannot shrink. Instead, missing data is filled in with `NaN`s (possibly even the entire row).

Let's see how that looks like for `df_out`:

| Dataframe | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `df_union` | YES | YES | YES |
| `df_subset` | YES | YES | `NaN` |
| `df_intersection` | `NaN` | `NaN` | YES |
| `df_disjoint` | `NaN` | `NaN` | `NaN` |
| `df_superset` | YES | YES | YES |

**Conclusion:**

- Prevents expansion of the reference dataframe; any additional columns in dataframe to append are dropped
- Prevents shrinkage of the reference dataframe by filling in `NaN`s in missing columns of the appended dataframe
- Good solution if filling in missing data *is* and dataframe resizing is *not* acceptable

---

#### Alternative: Selecting reference columns after appending

A solution with the same behavior as the previous one would be to append the dataframe, then selecting the reference dataframe's columns *afterwards*:

```py
df.append(df_to_append, ignore_index=True)[df.columns]
```

This solution is a bit easier to read and parse, but may be less performant on larger operations.